# create subdomain using php dynamically when the server has cPanel environment

Tags: php, subdomain

I want to know how to create subdomain using PHP.
The server uses cPanel control panel and i have seen code but not clear of what it does.
Is there any php function to create subdomains?
Or do we have to rely the server settings for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have cPanel then you can use what i used.

very simple function provided my hosting company server guy.

http://vikku.info/programming/php/create-subdomain-dynamically-in-php-code-to-create-subdomains-in-server-using-php.htm

As the other use said i agree that php cannot do anything with this...

These functions call cPanel libraries indirectly and those functions can access server level functions because they will have permission to do that.

Comment: Its not supporting any more ... i tried it nothing works

Answer (score 2):

PHP has nothing to do with domain or subdomains. You have to configure your server application accordingly to achieve this.

If you are using apache, take a look in [their documentation about vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create subdomain programmatically using `/execute/SubDomain/addsubdomain`. Check this [cPanel documentation](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/cpanel/operation/addsubdomain/) for more information.

```
function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain) {
   $subdomainRequest = "/execute/SubDomain/addsubdomain?domain=" . $subDomain  . "&rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&dir=public_html/" . $subDomain . ".". $rootDomain;
 
    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) { return "Socket error";exit();}
 
    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
    
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $subdomainRequest."\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";
    
    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
        fgets($openSocket,128);
    }
    fclose($openSocket);
    $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";
    return "Created subdomain $newDomain";
}
echo create_subdomain("Subdomain","cPanel-Username","cPanel-Password","Root-Domain");
```